# how to choose the path for complex line integrals? (Explicit question)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have a small question about complex line integrals. I give an example to demonstrate what my question is. Consider the integral

$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z-1}dz.$$
If I want to calculate this integral, can I take the path $f:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{C},\; f(t)=1+2e^{rit}$ to calculate the integral? I'm not sure if I could take this path, because it's not centered in zero, i.e. does it's not a parametrization of $|z|=2$. With this path I get:

$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z-1}dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2e^{rit}}2ire^{rit}dt=ir2\pi$$ if I did not make a mistake.

A comparison with the Cauchy-Integral-formula:

gives me $$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z-1}dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2e^{rit}}2ire^{rit}dt=i2\pi$$, which isn't the same. But maybe I did a mistake in calculation. Is $f$ a possible choice for a path or has f to be centered in zero and has to be a parametrization of the boundary of $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|\le 2\}$?

Comment: Technically, since $|f(t)|!=2$, you can't chose that path without a shout-out to the theorem that allows you to change the curve.  You never say $r$ is an integer, but it has to be to even be a closed path, but you are really only supposed to choose a path that goes (clockwise, by default) around the curve described exactly once. If you go around more times, you multiple your result.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is this ok that the path is not centered in zero?

Comment: ok, everything is clear now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, you haven't made a mistake, the contour you've "wraps" around the point $1$, $r$ times.  The extra factor of $r$ is called the winding number.

Comment: oh yes, for r=1 the the winding number is 1. Is the path $f$ ok (my choice of the path gives me the correct sloution, but it could be luck)? Or has f to be centered in zero?

Comment: Once you learn the residue theorem, you will understand why you got the right answer even using the wrong contour.

Comment: @int The path does not need to be centered at $0$. Any closed path which has $1$ "inside" will give the same answer.

Comment: thanks!! Ok, good to know!

Comment: Namely $2\pi i\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the winding number.